# Leaflet create marker from ajax call data

Tags: leaflet, ajax

Get all the basic works with Leaflet and want to add markers using ajax call

```
    $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("GetLocationsServlet", function(data){
        markers = data.split(";");
        var length = markers.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            alert(markers[i]); // data print out ok
            L.marker(markers[i]).addTo(mymap); // Error
        }
    });
});
```

Got error when adding the marker to the map

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null
at Object.project (leaflet.js:5)
```

The data return from the ajax call is like this

```
[49.205036,-123.002846, "Riverway Sport Complex"];[49.22193,-123.01249, "Imperial@Patterson"];[49.214756,-122.9882, "Royal Oak @Rumble"]
```

It worked when I tried to manually add the marker by hard coding the data to the L.marker() function. i.e.

```
L.marker([49.205036,-123.002846, "Riverway Sport Complex"]).addTo(mymap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your data is still *string* type, which is not suitable as input to Leaflet Marker factory `L.marker`.

From your code and data sample, jQuery [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) performs an AJAX request and treats the response as text (in your `data` argument), that you refactor using the string method `split`. Therefore your `markers` array contains *string* representations:

```js
'[49.205036,-123.002846, "Riverway Sport Complex"]'
```

You can easily convert it into a proper JavaScript object using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
JSON.parse(markers[i])
```

Then you can properly instantiate your markers:

```js
L.marker(JSON.parse(markers[i])).addTo(mymap);
```